# What is wrong with ".replace"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone please help me understand what is wrong with this simple function?

```
function generateSKU(inputField) {
    return inputField.replace(" ",".");
}
```

TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of undefined.

I even tried 
    inputField.Value.replace() .. which produced the same error..
Also inputField.toString.replace().. also gives me the exact same error..

No matter what I do, I cannot apply any string function on this. There is NOTHING else in my script. Only this function. Its my first script ever.

Also, if I return only inputField, it returns fine and replaces the value.

I am using the function by calling it inside the cell like

```
=generateSKU(A1)
```

like that.

if anyone can help I'll be very obliged.

Comment: Are you certain that you're passing in a string value to `generateSKU()`?

Comment: How do you call the related function?

Comment: @Rubén I have written in the question that I am calling it inside a cell.

Comment: @MuhammadbinYusrat: I'm sorry. The error message that you got is confusing. If A1 is a blank cell, the value passed to the custom function is an empty string, not "undefined". What is the value of A1? Please consider to create a demo spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is being called without a parameter (or is being passed something that resolves as `undefined` or `null`). Empty cells perhaps? If you're not controlling the invocation, you'll need to guard it:

```
function generateSKU(inputField) {
    if (inputField) {
        return inputField.replace(" ",".");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am invoking the function by writing in in place of where we write a formula.

Comment: You see, the problem is if I simply 'return' the inputField, the target field does get the "TEXT" from the main field. And if I type typeof(inputField) I DO get 'string' but as soon as i call replace, it doesn't work.

Comment: The issue was with the page that was loaded. It was giving an error when I posted the question and without me touching the script it worked fine the next morning. Thank you all for the help.